# Enable Anti-Aliasing for WPF shapes

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing, antialiasing

It seems that many people are trying to turn OFF `anti-aliasing` in `WPF`, but I seem to have the opposite problem.  I am drawing shapes in `WPF`, and the edges are all aliased and ugly.  The worst part is that when I use a ScaleTransform to zoom out such that a shape is less than one pixel tall/wide, it disappears entirely.  How can I make them smooth and pretty?

Currently, I am drawing `Rectangles` and `Ellipses` and placing them in grids and `StackPanels`.

After a lot of googling, I found out how to get my images to `anti-alias` by using the following line in my window's constructor: `RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(this, BitmapScalingMode.Fant);`

However, this only affects my Images and not my Shapes.

Answer (score 1):

I have what I think is the same problem. Setting `SnapsToDevicePixels` to false works for me:

```
<Ellipse SnapsToDevicePixels="False" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `EdgeMode` the same way you set `BitmapScalingMode`

```
 RenderOptions.SetEdgeMode(this, EdgeMode.Unspecified);
```

But `Anti-Aliasing` is set as default so you should not need to change it, but give it a go :)

Also setting `SnapsToDevicePixels = true;` on your window may help with the shapes.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but they did not help :(